# Is it OK to hard-code a default value for an instance variable?

Tags: java, string, default

I have a instance variable in a new object I am coding that will almost always be a certain value. In this case its "N". Is it OK to hard-code a default value to a String instance variable?

```
private String aBusinessSwitch= "N";
```

Later on in a method I have an `if` condition that will only set the value to a "Y" in a few rare situations.

Would it be better to not hard-code a default value of "N" when I declare the field and instead add `else` to my `if` statement that sets it a "N"

```
if (isCold) {aBusinessSwitch = "Y"; }
  else {aBusinessSwitch = "N"; }
```

Comment: How many values can that `String` take? Maybe `String` is not the appropriate type.

Comment: It looks like your code is "stringly typed". Why aren't you using a boolean?

Comment: I've removed some of the "hardcoded string" focus; more could be removed as well. The question could be about most any type and the question is the same: *"Would it be better to not [specify] a default value when I declare the field and instead add else to my if statement that sets it?"*

Comment: In my specific case I am sending text into a XML file. So using a boolean isn't really possible.

Comment: You say "later on in a method" which implies "not in the constructor" so keep in mind that your String actually has three possible values: "Y", "N" and null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer is 'this is frowned upon unless you need the ability to store a virtually unlimited variety of values'.

Do you need more than two values?  If not, consider a boolean.  If yes, consider an enum.  If you need a near-infinite number of values, there is a case to use a String.

Your program can still work perfectly if you choose to use strings for this purpose.  However, always keep in mind that every place you add complexity to your code, there are more opportunities for things to go wrong, and it presents a maintainability challenge in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bool in this case? Enum if you need more than yes & no.

Answer (score 1):

As others noted the usage of "N" and "Y" hint at String being the wrong type and a Boolean or an Enum might be a better choice. But that doesn't answer your question.

I wouldn't use a default value, because it splits the logic how this value is determined in two places. If you set it only in one place you might even be able to make it final if this place is inside the constructor, making the code a little simpler to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use Boolean or normal Instance variable , Enum is best for large number of values.